# SQL Count unique values from table

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL EXPRESS 2008.

I have a table that keeps track of all the Operating Systems users are using.  I want to get an accurate count for how many users are using each operating system.  Problem is the table has other entries, so whenever those are updated it adds another entry with that user's OS and ID.  So if I just search for 1 user, it returns 66 for the count, but that's not right it should just be 1.  How do I return a count value for each OS by unique ID?  `[MAC Address ID]` is the users unique ID, but there can be many entries with that users ID.

I've tried the following queuery:

```
USE db1
SELECT Windows.[Windows Version], COUNT(Topology.[MAC Address ID])
FROM Topology
JOIN Windows ON Windows.[Windows Version ID] = Topology.[Windows Version ID]
WHERE Topology.[MAC Address ID] IN (28, 154)
GROUP BY Windows.[Windows Version], Topology.[MAC Address ID]
```

and it returns

[image]

Which isn't right, my where clause is only searching for 2 users, so I should just have a total count of 2, not 72.  Should be 1 for row 1 and 1 for row 2.  (Ideally after removing the where clause I should see the count of users using each OS).

This is what my Topology table looks like:

[image]

Basically I would like to remove the WHERE clause and just be able to chart the # of users using each OS.

Comment: I think you need to remove  Topology.[MAC Address ID] in group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "distinct" to the count aggregation function, and just `group by` on Windows.[Windows Version]:

```
SELECT Windows.[Windows Version], COUNT(distinct Topology.[MAC Address ID])
FROM Topology
JOIN Windows ON Windows.[Windows Version ID] = Topology.[Windows Version ID]
WHERE Topology.[MAC Address ID] IN (28, 154)
GROUP BY Windows.[Windows Version]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to simplify your topology table and get distinct results containing only the information of interest:

```
USE db1

  SELECT Windows.[Windows_Version], COUNT(simplifiedTopology.[MAC_Address _ID])
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT [MAC_Address_ID], [Windows_Version_ID] FROM Topology ) simplifiedTopology
    JOIN Windows ON Windows.[Windows_Version_ID] = simplifiedTopology.[Windows_Version_ID]
   WHERE simplifiedTopology.[MAC_Address_ID] IN (28, 154)
GROUP BY Windows.[Windows_Version], Topology.[MAC_Address_ID]
```